# Solve $\cot \theta = \sqrt{3}$ for $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

$\cot \theta = \sqrt{3}$
I have tried $\tan$ inverse of $\dfrac 1{\sqrt{3}}$

I'm lost and It would be great if someone could put a step by step explanation.

Comment: So what is $\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$?  How does this succeed or fail in answering your question?

Comment: Hint: If $\tan\theta = 1/\sqrt3$, then we have
$$
\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1/2}{\sqrt3/2}
$$

Comment: what is the angle that gives sqrt of 3 when 1/tan is used on it

Answer (score 1):

You can compute as follows: $$\cot \theta =\sqrt 3$$

$$\frac {\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}=\sqrt 3$$

$$\cos \theta = \sqrt 3 \sin \theta$$

$$\cos^2\theta = 3 \sin^2 \theta$$

$$1=\cos^2\theta +\sin^2 \theta=4\sin^2\theta$$

$$\sin \theta =\pm \frac 12$$

But take care to use the values of $\theta$ for which sine and cosine have the same sign (squaring has added some spurious values)

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have 
$$\cot\theta=\sqrt3$$  $$\frac{1}{\tan\theta}=\sqrt3$$   $$\tan\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$$$\tan\theta=\tan\frac{\pi}{6}$$ 
Writing the general solution for $\theta$, we get 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\theta=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}}}$$
Where, $n$ is any integer

Comment: Could someone please explain the reason for what is wrong in the answer?